Icon changes when clicking on a new webpage
I have a vertical menu where people can switch between pages. When I'm on the main screen the icons are:
However, when I click on the 'soort' page the icon of partijen changes to:

This is my first time working with html, so I have no idea where to look. The sidebar is in a shared view. The icons are from https://iconify.design/ but they don't even have this design on their website.
This is the code for the sidebar:
@{
    TempData.Keep();
    string? currentPage = ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Path;
    var userRole = ViewBag.RolId;
}

<!-- Menu -->
<aside id="layout-menu" class="layout-menu menu-vertical menu bg-menu-theme">

  <div
    class='app-brand demo @((@ViewData["navbarFull"] != null && Convert.ToBoolean(@ViewData["navbarFull"])) ? "d-xl-none" : "")'>
    <a asp-controller="Dashboards" asp-action="Index" class="app-brand-link">
      <span class="app-brand-logo demo">
        <img src="~/img/illustrations/blaadje.png" alt="leaf" style="max-width:25px"/>

      </span>
      <span class="app-brand-text demo menu-text fw-bold ms-2">@TempData.Peek("appName")</span>
    </a>

    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="layout-menu-toggle menu-link text-large ms-auto d-block d-xl-none">
      <i class="bx bx-chevron-left bx-sm align-middle"></i>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="menu-inner-shadow"></div>

  @* ! Full version menu-items *@
  <ul class="menu-inner py-1">
    <!-- Dashboard -->
    <li class='menu-item@(currentPage == "/Dashboard/Index" ? " active" : "")'>
        <a asp-controller="Dashboard" asp-action="Index" class="menu-link">
            <i class="menu-icon tf-icons bx bx-home-circle"></i>
            <div>Dashboard</div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <!-- Partijen -->
    <li class='menu-item@(currentPage == "/Partij/Index" ? " active" : "")'>
        <a asp-controller="Partij" asp-action="Index" class="menu-link">
            <i class="menu-icon tf-icons bx bx-leaf"></i>
            <div>Partijen</div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <!-- Soorten-->
        <li class='menu-item@(currentPage == "/Soort/Index" ? " active" : "")'>
            <a asp-controller="Soort" asp-action="Index" class="menu-link">
                <i class=" menu-icon tf-icons bx bxs-color-fill"></i>
                <div>Soort</div>
            </a>
        </li>
  </ul>

</aside>

Edit: The inspect when being on the 'Soort' space shows this:

Can anyone give me a hint or a clue about where or how this went go wrong?

Have you used your browser devtools inspect facility to see exactly what CSS is being applied in both cases and from where it has come?

I think I did. I checked the inspect but indeed just shows the leaf. The same it shows when looking at another page. When looking at the design, it says :
/bx-leaf:before{ content: "\e99a"}  which is also what is says when looking at another webpage. All the other webpages work except for the specific "Soort" which i've added myself. @AHaworth

Have you checked whether you are using the same font on that page as on the other pages? It looks as if you are not.

The code appears to set an active class on the li element for the current menu item, so go and check if the ::before pseudo element on the i element inside gets any different formatting applied, based on its ancestor having or not having that class. (I'm guessing that the content property probably gets overwritten.)

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You will take reference of this given code below:



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script>
        window.onload=function(){
        document.querySelector('a[id="/Soort"]').addEventListener('click',function(){
            debugger
            document.querySelector('a[id="/Partij"]>i').classList="new icon class";
        })
    }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" id="/Soort">Soort</a>
    <a href=" #" id="/Partij"><i class="test">Partij</i></a>

</body>
</html>





Explain why your answer should help OP

@Justinas My code is only for reference not the exact answer.
